# how to use '{' with variables in string (PHP)

Tags: php, string

I want to output a string like this "{$myvar}" but it doesn't work.
if for example `$var = 1;`

```
    echo "$var";     // output "1"
    echo "{$var}";   // output "1"
    echo "\{$var\}"; // output "\{1\}"
```

how do I get "{1}" as a result ???

thanks

Comment: You Can try  echo "{{$var}}";

Comment: `echo '{' . $var . '}';`